# How to get a jQuery script to work in blogger?

Tags: jquery, carousel, blogger

I want to implement a carousel using bootstrap in blogger, the standard carousel is working but I don't want the 5 seconds interval and that the carousel pauses on mouse hoover.  I've tried putting the code in the `<head>`, `<body>` and in the blogger page code, but it doesn't work.  As I stated before, everything with bootstrap and jQuery is working, but only what I described is not (and makes me wonder if I want to implement another jQuery effects if they will ever work or will be just lose of time).  Thank you for your support.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.carousel').carousel({
    interval: 2000;
    pause: null;
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Any errors in the browser console?

Comment: @Owlvark Thanks for your reply, I didn't think about that; right now I checked and it showed " SyntaxError: missing } after property list ", I changed the ";" for "," to separate the parameters and now it works. Thank you again, if you wouldn't point me to that I'd spent hours and still missing it! I hope this help someone else out there having the same problem.